# Is there any issue for new csproj format to references old csproj or vise versa

Tags: c#, nuget, csproj

we're starting to migrate our old csproj projects to the new ones. naturally this processes takes time so we won't be migrating all of our projects\nugets at once. From what I've been reading the new csproj projects fetch only top level dependencies directly, while the old ones also fetches transitive references. so my questions is:

Is there any issue when a new csproj project\nuget references an old ones **or vise versa**?

Comment: no, there is no problem when old format project has references to the new one. Except that you will need Net Core SDK to be installed on all computers used to compile the source code

Comment: direct vs transitive packages is also more nuanced, although your understanding is either incorrect, or you explained it in a different way than others usually do. Non-SDK style projects support both packages.config and PackageReference, but SDK style projects only support PackageReference. packages.config lists packages you want to use, plus all dependencies, and NuGet only downloads packages listed in packages.config. With PackageReference, the project lists only what it wants to use, and NuGet downloads transitive dependencies and makes them available to the project.